# SSRS second entry never shows up in scale out deployment screen

Tags: availability-groups, ssrs

I am trying to setup two SSRS servers in a scale-out deployment that use a Always-On availability group for the database.

- The AG is setup and working.
- I have both SSRS servers using the AG listener on the Database page
  of the Report Server Configuration Manager.
- All credentials in SSRS configuration manager are using domain
  accounts.

Should work right?

When I go to the Scale-out Deployment page in the SSRS configuration manager I only ever get one entry in the list.
And the entry seems to flip back and forth between the two SSRS server.

i.e. when I look at the list on the Scale-out Deployment page, one minute it will say ServerA the next minute it will say ServerB but it never shows both at the same time so I can add ServerB.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wound up contacting MS for a solution to this.  Turns out when the servers were setup, an image was used (AWS).  As a result, the Installation ID for both servers were identical.  Here is the solution from MS:

> We tried to add Reportserver DB to AG and configure, still we were
> facing the issue.
>
> From dbo.keys we can see that installation id is same in config files
> of both servers.
>
> I tried to replicate the issue in my Lab by giving the same
> installation id and followed below steps to resolve the issue.
>
> Please use below action plan and let us know if it works. Please let
> us know if you need help in performing below steps so that I will
> schedule a meeting.
>
> 1. Go to SQL server instance and run below query. We will get a sample
>    id.  [image]
> 2. Go to config file in the server which is not working now Path :
>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting
>    Services\SSRS\ReportServer File name : rsreportserver.config Open this
>    file and search for   And change the installation ID
>    to the one which we got from the query in step1 Restart the service.
> 3. Check dbo.keys for new installation id as shown below. [image]
> 4. If you are still facing issue related to encryption keys. Please
>    delete the encryption key and restart the service. 5) Add the server
>    in scale out deployment after this step.